# onActivityResult returns intent data null Firebase Auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to use firebase authentication. The code was working well before but all of the sudden the intent data on onActivityResult() started returning null value.

```
SignInButton signInButton;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      //Default codes

    GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this,this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
}

public void signInBtn(){
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Button signInButton;
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;


mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuthStateListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            updateUI(user);
        }
    };


GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();


@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}


@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(mAuthStateListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
    }
    mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}


 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        } else {
            // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            updateUI(null);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    }

// [START auth_with_google]
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.

                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
// [END auth_with_google]

// [START signin]
private void signIn() {
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
// [END signin]


private void updateUI(FirebaseUser user) {
    if (user != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, HomeActivty.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    // An unresolvable error has occurred and Google APIs (including Sign-In) will not
    // be available.
    Toast.makeText(this, "Google Play Services error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

This is my completely working Google Auth with Firebase code. 
 If this code doesn't solve your problem, please upload the code you wrote in your         **handleSignInResult()** method

Comment: Thanks !! It worked flawlessly. Can you help me with firebase storage? Having problem with it too..

Comment: haven't had a chance to work with the Firebase Storage, but sure i'll try my best. tell me what problem are you facing with it?